# How to create a for loop that checks an element of a list against an element of a list contained in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to assign a topic/category to a series of web page titles. I was thinking about creating first a list containing all the page titles I need and then a dictionary composed of topics and their related words (it would be a dictionary with lists as values and topic names as keys).

Next, I would like to populate a table or simply returning the output in a tabular format so that I can manipulate it in Excel and the output should have the page titles in one column and the topic assigned in another column. Can you please help me out with this task?

Below I provide an example of what the list and the dictionary would look like...

```
page_titles = [ "How to measure insulin", "Advice for general practitioners", "Medications for HIV"]

topic_terms = { "diabetes" : ["insulin", "sugar"], "HIV" : ["HIV", "medication for HIV"] }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code!

Comment: What is your output supposed to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Not very efficient, but it shoul do the trick

```
outputlist = []

for page_title in page_titles:
    for topic in topic_terms:
        for keyword in topic_terms[topic]:
            if keyword in page_title:
                outputlist.append([page_title, topic])
```

Comment: Using Pandas you can turn the list into a DataFrame and export it to csv or Excel.

Answer (score 0):

```
to_write = []
for title in page_titles:    
    for topic, rel_words in topic_terms.items():
        for word in rel_words:
            if word in title:
                to_write.append((title, topic))
```

to_write will be a list of tuples where the first item is the title and the second is the topic. Use that to write out your excel sheet.